# Importing files from different directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I have the following folder structure:

```
Python_Game/src/domain/boards.py
Python_Game/tests/test.py
```

I'm trying to import function boards.py to test.py.

I've tried:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../src')
import domain
from domain import boards
```

and a lot of other attempts (including tipps in StackOverflow too) but so far I couldn't manage to import properly . Please give me some piece of advice.

I am working with Python 3.7.4, domain and tests folders contains `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Have you tried using `import ..src.domain.boards`?

Answer (score 0):

From your src directory :

```
import domain.boards as boards
```

From your Python_Game directory:

```
import src.domain.boards as boards
```

And follow the same logic for tests

Comment: But when I'm trying to import boards from test.py file I need firstly to go to parent directory... I think that's why this option is not working correctly for tests directory

Answer (score 0):

To access boards from tests:

```
import sys
#use full path for your boards file; if you are on windows replace / with \\
sys.path.append('Python_Game/src/domain/boards.py')

#import entire module:
import boards as boards

#or import specific functions/variables
from boards import function_name
```